# Extending foliations of submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, foliations

Take a manifold $M \cong \Sigma \times \mathbb{R}$, in which there are two submanifolds (of the same dimensions), $S_1$ and $S_2$, such that $S_i \cong \sigma_i \times \mathbb R$, and both are disjoint. Each of these submanifolds has a foliation $\sigma_{i}(t)$. Does there exist a foliation of $M$, $\Sigma(t)$, such that it is compatible with both? That is, for $t \in \mathbb R$, we have $\sigma_i(t) \subset \Sigma(t)$.

If this is not true, what are possible conditions for this to be true? It's obviously true in some cases at least (when the submanifolds inherit the foliation from the manifold). I suspect that for instance taking two copies of $(0,1) \times \mathbb R$ in $\mathbb R^2$ along the axis $y$ would not admit any such foliation if the first copy was foliated by lines according to their coordinates $y$ while the other was foliated by the reverse $-y$.

Answer (score 1):

Goggle my paper "on extending local foliations" in the quarterly journal in 1977. I addressed the following general question: given a compact smooth manifold X and a finite collection of codimension q embedded submanifolds each with trivial normal bundles when could the local product foliations be extended to a global foliation. While in general the answer is no, there are a number of positive results.

Comment: The goal of MSE is to provide a more-or-less self-contained repository of questions and answers.  While I am sure that the results in your paper are relevant, a reference to a paper (especially an incomplete reference) does not fit this mission.  Can you please expand a little on your results?  You say that there are a number of positive results; could you give a few examples, please?

Comment: I don't mean to be secretive I just don't know what the copyright rules are.

Comment: MSE's copyrights are not going to be an issue, and fair use dictates that you can summarize the results here.  I also worry that if your work is held under a restrictive copyright or if the actual paper is behind a paywall, it is *really* not in the spirit of MSE to provide a vague partial reference, as the paper isn't even going to be accessible to some subset of the folk who are interested in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article:

https://doi.org/10.1016/j.geomphys.2018.01.021

I think that, by using the *characteristic distribution*, you may prove the following:

Let $M$ be a manifold with $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ as embedded submanifolds which may be separated by two open subsets of $M$ (for example closed embedded submanifolds). Assume that both manifolds have associated a foliation $\mathcal{F}_{N_{1}}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{N_{2}}$, respectively. Then, there exists a foliation of $M$ extending both which, furthermore, satisfies some condition of *maximality*.